# iMac gets stuck halfway through boot

Tags: imac, disk-utility, startup

A couple of days ago my iMac (Late 2009) stopped turning on. It starts booting and the progress bar under the Apple logo goes to just under halfway before it turns off. Booting into recovery mode and trying to reinstall El Capitan doesn't work because it says the hard disk is locked. I tried running the `chflags 0` and `chmod` to unlock it that are suggested around [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4091299?tstart=0) from both single user mode and the recovery terminal but to no avail.

The files on the hard drive are all still there, so I tried to use `cp` to copy some stuff from there to USB disk, but it consistently crashes midway through the copy and goes to the "your computer has had a problem" screen. I've also tried zapping the PRAM.

Running first aid on Disk Utility from recovery mode says "file system verify or repair failed". I also tried booting in verbose mode and noticed it crashes after running `fsck_hfs` and fails, which I assume is what disk utility is doing behind the scenes.

Any advice on how to backup and then do a clean install or reinstall from recovery or just fix it would be very appreciated!

Comment: Most likely your hard drive is failing.  What you should do is replace it with a new drive (SSD is best) and try to recover your data by attaching your old drive via USB

Comment: If it is failing, wouldn't that mean the files are inaccessible?

Comment: Not necessarily; you may be able to access *some* files.  The fact you have so many errors related to reading your drive is an indication of a failing drive.  Issue the command `diskutil info disk0 | grep -i smart` and post the results.   Do you have a Time Machine back up?

Comment: Also, to find out what specific model you have issue the command `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep Identifier`.

Comment: Oh, I see. It says "SMART Status: Verified" for the diskutil command and "Model Identifier: iMac10,1" for system_profiler. And no, no time machine backup.

Comment: You should run the Apple Hardware Test. If you haven't got I/O errors in your logs from the hard drive, it might be a RAM failure instead. RAM failure can lead to disk corruptions.

Comment: Holding down D on boot didn't load the hardware test, so I tried it with the install cd in as well, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symptoms you describe are indicative of a disk drive corruption.  It could be  physical (hardware) or just a file system corruption.

Recovery will require booting from a different drive so you can copy files over.  You can boot from an external USB that has a clean install of OS X (El Capitan would be the latest as your system is not capable of running Sierra) or replace the internal drive with an SSD and attempt recovery via USB.

Personally, I prefer the latter.

The full repair guide is available on [ifixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+24-Inch+EMC+2267+Hard+Drive+Replacement/9028), but here are the basic steps you need to go through

You will need the following:

- New SSD Drive.  I recommend the [Samsung EVO series](http://radnex.us/Samsung_EVO_850)
- [USB to 3.5" SATA adapter](http://radnex.us/usb3-hdd-adapter-laptop-desktop-power).  This is so you can access the drive for recovery
- El Captian Installation Media. Note that this vintage iMac (2009 through Late 2011) will support up to High Sierra - 10.13.x
- Suction Cups (for glass removal)
- Torx T10 screwdriver
- plastic spudger for connector removal
- 2.5" to 3.5" kit so the new drive will fit
- External HDD for Time Machine (Optional, but highly, highly recommended)

**Remove the glass.**  The good news is that the glass panel is held in with magnets which you can remove with suction cups and the LCD itself is held in with 10 Torx screws.

[image: imac display removal]
[image]

**Replace the drive.** Once you have the panel removed, you will get access to the 3.5" Hard Drive (see pic below)

[image: imac panel off]

When you replace the drive, ensure that you replace the temperature sensor, otherwise you will end up with a fan that spins uncontrollably, and erroneous temperature readings.

Just reverse the steps to re-assemble your iMac.

**Clean Install OS X.** Using the boot media, do a clean installation of OS X.  Then reinstall your apps.

**Begin recovery**.  Using the USB to SATA adapter, hook up your old hard drive to your iMac via USB.  You should be able to mount it and `cp` (copy) your data off.  Once done, you can discard your drive (it's quite old and I wouldn't trust it for data storage anymore).  Take it to your local electronics recycler or sell it "as is, for parts only" on eBay; many recovery shops will take it for the PCB or server motors.  You won't get much, but it keeps it out of a landfill.

**Set up Time Machine**.  I can't stress this enough... having a backup *besides* (or in addition to) iCloud is extremely important.  Right now, you are finding out first hand how valuable a Time Machine backup can be.

Answer (score 0):

That was the exact problem that I faced! Most likely it is a file system corruption that can only be fix via a clean install of the OS.

**1. Backup all important files and folders**

You can use terminal to selectively backup files from your mac, especially the files and folders in your Home folder.

`cp -r -v /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user-name/ /Volumes/Backup`

This is the command, where `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user-name` is the source and `/Volumes/Backup` is the destination. The parameter `-r` means to copy recursively including the files inside each subdirectory. `-v` is to enable verbose mode, so that you can see all the details while the command is running. You would need to change the hard disk and folders name according to those inside your iMac and external drive.

There are [other methods to recover your files](https://ngszekiat.com/5-ways-to-backup-mac-wont-boot-recovery-mode/), but I personally prefer to backup via the `cp` command.

**2. Install The OS**

Before you jump to install, make sure all your files are properly backup. Check by opening the files to make sure they are not damaged.

You can boot into recovery mode by holding down on the `CMD` + `R` keys until you see the Apple logo. Choose the Reinstall Mac OS option. You'll need to connect to the internet to download and restore the system