# Black screen after login and frozen loading wheel

Tags: macos, performance, error, login-screen

I am trying to help a friend with their machine. They are using an iMac (3-4 years old) running 10.12.

At first, their issue was at login. They would get to the login screen, enter their password, see the loading wheel for 1-2 seconds, then the screen would black out. But the machine is still on. Happened for a few times.

Now, though. It just powers on, get to the first loading screen, and then freezes. Tried multiple times. Same thing.

I wasn't sure what to do, so I had them follow this guide, [What to do when your Mac displays a blank screen and the cursor after a macOS update](https://betanews.com/2016/12/15/blank-screen-cursor-macos-update-fix/).

- I had them reset the PRAM three times.
- Then boot to Single User Mode, and enter the commands in the article.
- There seemed to be some errors in the drive, but I am not qualified to interpret them.
- [Here are screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Febjd.jpg) of all the entries and readouts in Single User Mode.

[image: Screenshot#1]

[image: Screenshot#2]

[image: Screenshot#3]

What seems to be the issue, and what should I have them do next?

Comment: Most likely your HDD has crashed.  Check out https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/267433/119271 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/238093/119271

Answer (score 1):

the part you want to pay attention to is the

> CoreStorageGroup::completeIORequest - error 0xe000002ca detected for
>   LVG "Macintosh HD" (...) disk2: I/O error.

I Googled that error code and found a few reports online of people with that issue.  It looks to me like your hard-drive is failing (but that may not be true - it's just a guess).. any time I see the "I/O error", I typically assume the data is in jeopardy even if there's a chance it might not be.  You want to be as safe as possible.  I hope you have backups .. if you don't, you'll want to treat this situation as though you could lose all your data.

*Hire a professional to make backups of your hard-drive and advise you on your best next steps.*  It never hurts to talk to Apple, if it's under warranty they may be able to help.  If not, you'll want to decide if you want to get a new hard-drive put in (depending on the year your iMac was manufactured, it could be very easy or very difficult) or just buy a new iMac.